# bash script into windows 10 powershell version

Tags: bash, powershell

My Python2.7 and pypy(using virtualenv) are all under windows 10 environment. From a README file in simulation software, below includes a 'for loop" script in Bash command. How would I convert below 'for loop" (three lines) Bash commands into equivalent Windows 10 Powershell commands?

"It's better to run several processes in parallel, for instance:

```
$ for i in {1..10}; do
$ time $pypy epto.py conf_epto/ $i > conf_epto/run-$i.log $
$ done
```

- And then to obtain stats for all runs:

```
    $pypy genStats.py conf_epto 10
```

- This will output the stats to stdout and also generate dumps in gnuplot format."

I tried to run Powershell commands but face error:

```
(my-pypy-env) PS C:\Users\Acer\dev\pypy27home\my-pypy-env\SimpleDA-master> for ( $i = 1; $i -le 10; $i++) {
>> $pypy epto.py conf_epto/ $i > conf_epto/run-$i.log $
>> done}
At line:2 char:7
+ $pypy epto.py conf_epto/ $i > conf_epto/run-$i.log $
+       ~~~~~~~
Unexpected token 'epto.py' in expression or statement.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach ($i in 1..10) {
  Measure-Command { & $pypy epto.py conf_epto/ $i > conf_epto/run-$i.log } | Out-Host
}

& $pypy genStats.py conf_epto 10
```

- [`foreach ($i in 1..10)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_foreach) loops over the elements of array `1..10`, created with PowerShell's [range operator (`..`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators#range-operator-); the body of compound statements such as `foreach` is always enclosed in `{ ... }` in PowerShell.
- [`Measure-Command`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/measure-command) is PowerShell's equivalent to Bash's `time` builtin; the command whose execution to measure is passed as a script block (`{ ... }`).

  - The command inside the script block basically works the same as in Bash, except that in Windows PowerShell `>` creates "Unicode" - UTF16-LE - files by default (in PowerShell *Core* it is UTF-8 without a BOM). `>` is an effective alias of the [`Out-File`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-file) cmdlet; to use a different encoding, pipe to it and use the `-Encoding` parameter (e.g., 
    `... | Out-File -Encoding utf8 conf_epto/run-$i.log`), though note that in Windows PowerShell `-Encoding utf8` invariably creates a UTF-8 file *with a BOM*.
  - `time` outputs its result directly to the terminal rather than to stdout; so does [`Out-Host`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/out-host); it bypasses PowerShell's stdout equivalent, the [success [output] stream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_redirection).
- PowerShell requires use of `&`, the [call operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators#call-operator-), for executing a command whose name or path is specified as a *variable* (`$pypy`); this requirement stems from PowerShell having two distinct [parsing modes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_parsing).

Comment: Glad to hear it, @CaseyYeow; my pleasure.